# Handle unhandled iOS app Universal links: return NO ir use openURL:?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, ios-universal-links

On [Apple documentation of Universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) it is stated that:

> If you receive an invalid URL in an activity object, it’s important to fail gracefully. To handle an unsupported URL, you can call openURL: on the shared application object to open the link in Safari.

BUT, if we look at [UIApplicationDelegate's - application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:
documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:) we see, that this method can return `NO` if the app can't handle received link:

> Return Value:
>   YES to indicate that your app handled the activity or NO to let iOS know that your app did not handle the activity.

I've tried returning NO and it works very well - it opens the link in safari. So why Apple suggests using `openURL:` instead of returning `NO`? As for me, it looks better to return `NO` and let iOS decide what to do next.

Comment: I have the same question: In my experience, nevertheless, if I return NO, my app is still opened, but nothing happens (showing the front page).

I agree that according to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/qa/qa1916/_index.html http://archive.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=24441

The system should act as if my app were not installed at all, i.e. should open the link in Safari.

Anyone has some more info on this topic?